# How could I know subprocess is waiting for input on GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, subprocess

I am writing a top-script (python) to control the EDA tools on IC design flow, the top-script have a GUI (python-tkinter), run EDA tools with subprocess.Popen(), print the stdout on the GUI.

Sometime EDA tool will not exit but waiting for input, then the GUI will hang and wait for my input, but top-script cannot catch the right stdout message from subprocess.stdout, and cannot put my input into subprocess.

Below is part of my top-script.

```
class runBlocks():
    ... ...
    def subprocessRun(self):
        # run EDA tool "runCommand" with subprocess.Popen.
        self.RC = subprocess.Popen(runCommand, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        # save subprocess stdout into queue.
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        getRunProcessThread = threading.Thread(target=self.getRunProcess)
        getRunProcessThread.setDaemon(True)
        getRunProcessThread.start()

        # update GUI with the stdout (on queue).
        self.updateRunProcess()

        # wait for subprocess finish.
        (stdout, stderr) = self.RC.communicate()
        return(self.RC.returncode)

    def getRunProcess(self):
        # no block getting subprocess.stdout
        while self.RC.poll() == None:
            stdoutLine = str(self.RC.stdout.readline(), encoding='utf-8')
            self.queue.put(stdoutLine)

    def updateRunProcess(self):
        # if there is still something from subprocess.stdout, print them into GUI Text.
        while self.RC.poll() == None or not self.queue.empty():
            if self.queue.empty():
                time.sleep(0.1)
                conitnue
            else:
                line = self.queue.get_nowait()
                if line:
                    # "self.runProcessText" is a Text on GUI, accept EDA tool output message.
                    self.runProcessText.insert(END, line)
                    # "self.runProcessText" is on "self.frame6", after inserting new message, update the frame.
                    self.frame6.update()
                    self.runProcessText.see(END)
```

If I run the EDA tool on terminal directly, it will stop and waiting for my input.

```
$ dc_shell-t -64 -topo -f ./analyze.run.tcl -o analyze.log
...
$ #quit
$ dc_shell-topo>
```

If I run the EDA tool with my top-script, the subprocess.stdout will stop on message "#quit", I cannot get message "dc_shell-topo>".

```
...
#quit
```

I know the subprocess is waiting for my input, but GUI will stop on the message "#quit", and hang with "time.sleep(0.1)" on the while command.

I also tried replace "time.sleep(0.1)" with "self.GUItop.after(100, self.updateRunProcess)", then stdout will go through "dc_shell-topo>" command without any input, then finish directly.

```
...
dc_shell=topo>
Memory usage for main task 82 Mbytes.
CPU usage for this session 6 seconds ...
Thank you...
```

My expected behavior is:

1. When command stop with "dc_shell-topo>" on subprocess, I can get the message with subprocess.stdout.
2. GUI will not hang when waiting for my intput.

My questions are:

1. Why use "time.sleep()" and "self.GUItop.after()" can affect the subprocess.stdout message?
2. When EDA tool is waiting for input with message "dc_shell-topo>" on subprocess, how could i get such message on subprocess.stdout()?
3. When using self.GUItop.after, the GUI Text before the subprocess finish (It is waiting for cpu free), but without self.GUItop.after, GUI will hang on time.sleep() command, how to solve such issue?

I thinks this is really a headache problem, I have read thousands related questions on google, but none of them can answer my question.